# Pilcrow ¶ - occurs when CONCATENATE Char(10) with numbers?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, userform

I have a simple formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(K3&CHAR(10)&L3&CHAR(10)&M3&CHAR(10)&N3)
```

or

```
=K2&CHAR(10)&L2&CHAR(10)&M2&CHAR(10)&N2
```

This creates a Cell in the way I want:

```
1
2
3
4
```

However, when I populate a textbox with that Cell I get the following:

```
1¶2¶3¶4
```

What is odd, is that I am using exactly the same formula with text, and it appears correctly in both the cell and in the textbox.

```
One
Two
Three
Four
```

The code for the textbox is:

```
Me.TextBox18 = Sheets("QCData").Cells(i, "M").Value
```

I have tried:

```
Me.TextBox18 = Sheets("QCData").Cells(i, "M").Text
```

But it didn't make any difference.

A hour spent on Google really didn't get me any closer so I was hoping someone had come across this before and worked out a way to fix it?

Comment: You have to set the MultiLine property of the TextBox to True.

Comment: Thank you, I did that for the text box, thought I had copied and pasted it.  Thank you :)